# AS3 > performance > if (myBooleanField) *VS* if (myObjectField != null) *VS* if (myIntField != 0)

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

Say I have a function called `drawGraphics` which runs very tight for 3 seconds under some predefined configuration.

In that function I may call `myDecorator.decorate()`, given that the field is not null.

I can run this code using two options:

```
if (myDecorator != null)
    myDecorator.decorate();
```

-or-

```
// during init:
isUsingDecorator = myDecorator != null; // boolean field

// ...
// during 'drawGraphics'
if (isUsingDecorator) 
    myDecorator.decorate();
```

Which is more efficient: comparing a field to null or asking if a boolean field is 'true' (or comparing an int field to 0) ?

Am I being over dramatic about performance here??

Thanks in advance

Eyal

Comment: This is hardly a relevant question since your second case is the first case + assignment. Second case for that reason simply cannot be faster.

Comment: The difference would be miniscule. Even in a 3 second duration I doubt you'd see even 1ms improvement with `isUsingDecorator`, the bottleneck is surely elsewhere. But you really need to take some measurements to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Most likely* resolving names takes far longer than actual comparison. But this depends greatly on your code structure, on the nesting of scopes and on the optimisations the compiler uses with it. *I doubt* that this very issue really matters in overall performance. I would guess that you are micro-optimizing here.

Anyway, what you could do to assess the issue is take a look at the bytecode that gets generated. Strip your code of irrelevant parts preserving the structure of scopes and decompile the result.

I.e. suppose you have this code in a single frame of an empty `bytecode.swf` movie:

```
var test:Function = function(){};
var check:Boolean = test != null;

var action:Function = function()
{
    if (test != null) {
        trace(1);
    }
    if (check) {
        trace(2);
    }   
};

action();
```

Use `flex_sdk_4.6\bin\swfdump.exe`:

```
swfdump.exe -abc -showbytecode bytecode.swf > bytecode.txt
```

Inspect `bytecode.txt` and find the following:

```
02 02 01 0B 0B 1C    var null::no name():
maxStack:2 localCount:1 initScopeDepth:11 maxScopeDepth:11
60 03                    getlex         :test
20                       pushnull       
13 07 00 00              ifeq           L0

5D 09                    findpropstrict :trace
24 01                    pushbyte       1
4F 09 01                 callpropvoid   :trace (1)
60 05                L0: getlex         :check
12 07 00 00              iffalse        L1

5D 09                    findpropstrict :trace
24 02                    pushbyte       2
4F 09 01                 callpropvoid   :trace (1)
47                   L1: returnvoid
```

Now we can see that comparing test to null takes three instructions: `getlex`, `pushnull`, `ifeq`; and checking a boolean results in two instructions: `getlex`, `iffalse`. And the only thing that matters here performance-wise is resolving identifiers with `getlex`.

So, to answer your question you need to figure out how long does it really take to resolve `myDecorator` in your particular context. For example, if `isUsingDecorator` is a local to method variable and `myDecorator` is not, you will definitely get better performance with the former. Once again, I doubt that this is what really matters.

P.S. You may as well use a primitive test below, but it's highly inaccurate when the difference in performance is so tiny or non-existent. Anyway, it can give you a hint at least: this is not what needs optimisation.

```
import flash.utils.setInterval;

var test:Function = function(){};
var check:Boolean = test != null;

var action:Function = function()
{
    var a:Date;
    var s:int, i:int;

    s = getTimer();
    for(i = 0;i<100000;i++) {
        if (test != null) {
            a = new Date(); // just chewing the fat     
        }
    }
    trace("a:"+(getTimer()-s));

    s = getTimer();
    for(i = 0;i<100000;i++) {
        if (check) {
            a = new Date(); // just chewing the fat     
        }
    }   
    trace("b:"+(getTimer()-s));
};

setInterval(action, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you Nox Noctis, great answer!  ... and testing this question with byte code is a great way to answer it...

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a relevant question since your second case is the first case + assignment. Second case for that reason simply cannot be faster.

Why also limiting to 2 options? Evaluating the instance directly is also perfectly valid:

```
if(myDecorator)
{ etc ....
```